# How to remove scientific notation from a log-log plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, formatting, scientific-notation

I'd like the y axis to show only the number 100, 200, and 300, and not in scientific notation. Any thoughts?

[Current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3KbV.png)

Simplified code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(2, 6, 20)
y = np.logspace(np.log10(60), np.log10(300), 20)

plt.scatter(x, y[::-1])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you want `ax.ticklabel_format(style="plain")`.  See [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major and minor locators determine the positions of the ticks. The standard positions are set via the `AutoLocator`. The `NullLocator` removes them. A `MultipleLocator(x)` shows ticks every multiple `x`.

For the y axis, setting standard tick positions shows the ticks at the top closer to each other, as determines by the log scale. Doing the same for the x axis, however, due to the large range, would put them too close together. So, for the x axis the positions determined by the `LogLocator` can stay in place.

The formatters control how the ticks should be displayed. The `ScalarFormatter` sets the default way. There is an option `scilimits` that determines for which ranges of values a scientific notation should be used. As 1.000.000 usually gets displayed as `1e6`, setting `scilimits=(-6,9)` avoids this.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(2, 6, 20)
y = np.logspace(np.log10(60), np.log10(300), 20)

plt.scatter(x, y[::-1])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
ax = plt.gca()

# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.NullLocator())  # no minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())  # set regular formatting

# ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())  # major y tick positions in a regular way
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(100))  # major y tick positions every 100

ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.NullLocator())  # no minor ticks
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())  # set regular formatting

ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(-6, 9))  # disable scientific notation

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]